# Check string Format using Reg Ex

Tags: php, regex

I want to check the string if it is in the format of:

```
    presence-bits-{random string containing only numbers and letters}-reactions
    e.g. $inputString = presence-bits-asd3asd3-reactions
```

I tried using this preg_match with the following pattern

```
    preg_match('/(presence)-(bits)-(^[a-zA-Z\d]+$)-(reactions)$/', $inputString, $parts)
```

but its wrong.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `^$` anchors in your inner group. Also, you don't have to put parentheses around every word.

```
preg_match('/presence-bits-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-reactions$/', $inputString, $parts)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Also I need those parentheses so that I won't need to explode it later.

Comment: I take my comment back. It worked! I removed '+' when I removed the anchors that's why it didn't work from the start. Silly me. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need capture groups around fixed words? If you know what you are matching, you can use it without capturing it. The only thing you are interested in is the inner group (and that one still has parentheses)

Comment: Because that random string is an ID that i'll be using. hehe

Comment: @Jhn: Yes, that's what I said. But there's no sense in capturing the strings `presence`, `bits` and `reactions`

Comment: Oh yah. Makes sense, just realized it. Thanks for further explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

The ^ stands for line-begin and the $ for line end.

```
preg_match('/(presence)-(bits)-([a-zA-Z\d]+)-(reactions)/', $inputString, $parts)
```